# Numerating rows after a specified date in R

Tags: r, rows, days

This is most likely a really easy fix, but here goes. Quite simply, I am trying to numerate rows after a specific date in my dataframe. Here is an example of the data:-

```
Date<-structure(c(18485, 18486, 18487, 18488, 18489, 18490, 18491, 
            18492, 18493, 18494, 18495, 18496, 18497, 18498, 18499, 18500, 
            18501, 18502, 18503, 18504, 18505, 18506, 18507, 18508, 18509, 
            18510, 18511, 18512, 18513, 18514, 18515, 18516, 18517, 18518, 
            18519, 18520, 18521, 18522, 18523, 18524, 18525, 18526, 18527
), class = "Date")

Count<-c(54L, 42L, 44L, 52L, 51L, 47L, 53L, 45L, 41L, 56L, 45L, 56L, 
         52L, 57L, 48L, 47L, 52L, 58L, 51L, 41L, 53L, 155L, 123L, 98L, 
         90L, 84L, 71L, 58L, 50L, 54L, 45L, 58L, 48L, 49L, 60L, 41L, 60L, 
         46L, 40L, 50L, 49L, 57L, 58L)

df<-data.frame(Date,Count)
```

What I am trying to do is numerate the rows as 1 until the end of the data frame, but only after a specific date. Think of it as "number of days" after a date. For instance, I want to numerate the rows in a way which indicates the days after (and including) 2020-09-01, but I get this:-

```
df$intv_trend<-ifelse(df$Date<as.Date("2020-09-01"),0,1:22)

df

         Date Count intv_trend
1  2020-08-11    54          0
2  2020-08-12    42          0
3  2020-08-13    44          0
4  2020-08-14    52          0
5  2020-08-15    51          0
6  2020-08-16    47          0
7  2020-08-17    53          0
8  2020-08-18    45          0
9  2020-08-19    41          0
10 2020-08-20    56          0
11 2020-08-21    45          0
12 2020-08-22    56          0
13 2020-08-23    52          0
14 2020-08-24    57          0
15 2020-08-25    48          0
16 2020-08-26    47          0
17 2020-08-27    52          0
18 2020-08-28    58          0
19 2020-08-29    51          0
20 2020-08-30    41          0
21 2020-08-31    53          0
22 2020-09-01   155         22
23 2020-09-02   123          1
24 2020-09-03    98          2
25 2020-09-04    90          3
26 2020-09-05    84          4
27 2020-09-06    71          5
28 2020-09-07    58          6
29 2020-09-08    50          7
30 2020-09-09    54          8
31 2020-09-10    45          9
32 2020-09-11    58         10
33 2020-09-12    48         11
34 2020-09-13    49         12
35 2020-09-14    60         13
36 2020-09-15    41         14
37 2020-09-16    60         15
38 2020-09-17    46         16
39 2020-09-18    40         17
40 2020-09-19    50         18
41 2020-09-20    49         19
42 2020-09-21    57         20
43 2020-09-22    58         21
```

How can I get it so that 2020-09-01 is day 1 (as opposed to be day 22) and that the last date in the df is day 22, as opposed to day 21? As always, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `cumsum` based on date coming after your selected date. The advantage here would be you do not need to specify the number of dates needed.

```
df$intv_trend <- cumsum(df$Date >= as.Date("2020-09-01"))
```

**Output**

```
         Date Count intv_trend
1  2020-08-11    54          0
2  2020-08-12    42          0
3  2020-08-13    44          0
4  2020-08-14    52          0
5  2020-08-15    51          0
6  2020-08-16    47          0
7  2020-08-17    53          0
8  2020-08-18    45          0
9  2020-08-19    41          0
10 2020-08-20    56          0
11 2020-08-21    45          0
12 2020-08-22    56          0
13 2020-08-23    52          0
14 2020-08-24    57          0
15 2020-08-25    48          0
16 2020-08-26    47          0
17 2020-08-27    52          0
18 2020-08-28    58          0
19 2020-08-29    51          0
20 2020-08-30    41          0
21 2020-08-31    53          0
22 2020-09-01   155          1
23 2020-09-02   123          2
24 2020-09-03    98          3
25 2020-09-04    90          4
26 2020-09-05    84          5
27 2020-09-06    71          6
28 2020-09-07    58          7
29 2020-09-08    50          8
30 2020-09-09    54          9
31 2020-09-10    45         10
32 2020-09-11    58         11
33 2020-09-12    48         12
34 2020-09-13    49         13
35 2020-09-14    60         14
36 2020-09-15    41         15
37 2020-09-16    60         16
38 2020-09-17    46         17
39 2020-09-18    40         18
40 2020-09-19    50         19
41 2020-09-20    49         20
42 2020-09-21    57         21
43 2020-09-22    58         22
```

Comment: that is brilliant. And also makes work a bit easier too now that I don't have to specify the number of days. Thank you!